# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper

Tags: java, scala, maven, fasterxml, jackson-modules

I am trying to run a spark job. However everytime I try to get it to run locally it fails because of

```
caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper$class
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
```

My Pom File includes Jackson dependencies already

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

My scala version is 2.11.12 and spark 2.4.4. Looking online, it was recommended jackson dependencies match and they do.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you check if they are present in the dependent library location ?

Comment: @nrvaller jackson is a compile time dependency for spark. It is automatically pulled in when you add spark dependency. Are you explicitly adding jackson dependency in you pom file?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

This solved my issue, worked like a charm!
https://programming.vip/docs/resolution-of-jackson-version-conflict-in-spark-application.html